# How much sunlight is required for photosynthesis to peak?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I've read that photosynthesis peaks at some point over light intensities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PI_curve According to https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z9pjrwx/revision/5 suggests

> At very high light intensities, photosynthesis is slowed and then inhibited, but these light intensities do not occur in nature.

But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency seems to suggest otherwise

> most plants can only use ~10% of full mid-day sunlight intensity

If plants can only use ~10% of mid-day sunlight, then the intensity of mid-day sunlight would have been too high for the rate of photosynthesis to plateau.
Are the two incompatible or am I missing something?

Comment: Varies by plant

Comment: ^this. Also I would be cautious to assume that 10% of mid-day sunlight energy utilized by a plant translates into 100% energy utilization at a *tenth* of mid-day lighting conditions.